# trouble with double quotes first record of PHP array

Tags: php, sql-server, json

php5, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, OS 6.3.15063. i get $row data via mssql_fetch_assoc and stuff a PHP array with the $row data just fine when the first record does not have double quotes. subsequent row data can have double quotes, just not the first row. Error: "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" in jquery.min - so i cannot peruse and get helpful info from that. code:

```
$History_SQL = "
DECLARE @AID int;
SET @AID = $Activity_ID;
SELECT activityid, lpid, abstract, changeid, changestamp FROM cpy_activity_history 
WHERE activityid = @AID ORDER BY changestamp DESC;
";

  $History_results = mssql_query($History_SQL);

while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($History_results)) {
  $HistoryRecords[] = $row;
}
```

This works when record index[0] does not have double quotes, but when double quotes, errors out.

Interestingly, if i use:

```
$HistoryRecords[] = json_encode($row);

RESULT>>SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

then it gets past the error; but I am having trouble usind json_decode to get any useful information out of the array [not even getting js braces or anything, getting another record from another table, possibly because this value is not what it thought it was going to be/either way, not sure i am even starting down the right road with json_endode/decode.]

it could be i simply do need help learning how to decode each record coming out of the json encoded var. either way, does this problem look familiar, and any ideas for how to stop getting the error? NOTE: ultimately, i need to display the array information via javascript. other related posts do not seem to cover this scenario.  these double quotes are proving maddening. thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is super confusing. What is the issue? What happens if you do: `json_encode($HistoryRecords)` in your first code block? You say _"if I do this, then it goes past the error"_ while showing an actual error? What does that array look like before you encode it? Try `var_dump($HistoryRecords);` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Can you give us the data that's being returned, so that we might better be able to figure out what PHP wants that your'e not providing?
I'm guessing there are mismatched quotes or something similar, leading PHP to look for the end of an expression it isn't finding, but without seeing what PHP is seeing - we can't really do much.

Comment: htx!! trying hard to be clear: [1]input sql:... ages "birth to five" in Cumberland County...[2]original code: $HistoryRecords[]=$row; [all works when no d.quotes in the table record[0]/most recent; subsequent history recs can have d.quotes]. [3]when i do $HistoryRecords[]=json_encode($row), or json_encode($HistoryRecords), the output which uses this and another text var in a compare function, returns only the other var[confusing i know]. [4]var_dump yields the info as ... ages "birth to five" in Cumberland County...[5]so the php var looks fine, but the browser  error="missing ) after arg list"

Comment: confusing, i know, trying to isolate only the code that is relevant. perhaps advice on best way to encode $row, then decode it, and access ea var via js decoded? var i need to output into browser: $HistoryRecords[0]['abstract'].  whole thing feels strange, sorry for confusion. i'd rather leave and regroup than get dinged for a bad post.

Answer (score 0):

thx, All for helping!

the SYMPTOMS included the [a]browser crashing with console/js error: "missing ) after arg list", [b]a var in the code to display an erroneous field, unrelated to the sql used to create info for that var.

the REASON this occurred was that i had within PHP, a console.log that contained a PHP variable. so i was mixing js and PHP. the PHP was firing late and so at the time, the js console.log had nothing to display.

the CLUE which led to fixing this was noticing that the js msg was crashing in the browser, YET the php LOG_IT stmts *below the js* were working. the js was trying to console.log a msg that had a null value, and somehow a js var was getting loaded with wrong information. sheeze.

the CODE - before the fix the php echo from within the console.log was the culprit. i tossed the original offending stmt, but it was something like this:

```
<?php here in php land....., now i want to do a console.log....
?><script>console.log("show me info!: " <?php echo $info; ?></script><?php
...back in php land...
```

i commented out the "echo $info;" and things worked. of course i ripped it out altogether. funny, it would've cleared itself up when i stopped banging my head on the wall and simply decided to clean up and remove all the troubleshooting console.logs.

the CONCLUSION - an old lesson, "don't mix js and php", even in error logging!

thx again for all your help!

Comment: Your first conclusion should be "don't pass unquoted strings to `console.log`." Next conclusion should be "don't use deprecated database APIs that don't exist in current versions of PHP!"